# React + Typescript styled-icon as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

when I try to pass styled-icon as prop to component, i get an error:

Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected identifier.

```
import { PersonOutline } from 'styled-icons/material/PersonOutline'
```

here is props for my TextField component

```
import { StyledIcon } from 'styled-icons/types';


interface IProps {
  type: string;
  placeholder: string;
  icon: StyledIcon;
}

const TextField = (props: IProps) => {...
```

and my TextField looked like:

```
<TextField icon={<PersonOutline size="20" color={colors.gray500}/>} type={'text'} placeholder={'Name'} />
```

Comment: You are missing one `}` here `<TextField icon={<PersonOutline size="20" color={colors.gray500}/>} type={'text'} placeholder={'Name'} />`

So it should be like this `<TextField icon={<PersonOutline size="20" color={colors.gray500}/>} type={'text'} placeholder={'Name'} />}>`

Answer (score 0):

It was because

> If you are using Next.js, you likely also want to install next-plugin-styled-icons to take advantage of tree shaking.